# Why the code execution result is 10 ? JS syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, var

The code is:

```
x = 10;

if (x > 1) {
  var x = x + 1;
}

console.log(x);
var x;
```

The output of code execution is: 11

Why is it 11? , And Why is it not an error?

Comment: because 10 is NOT greater than 10 - and it's not an error, because 1: `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of the current execution context, and 2: multiple `var` declarations in the same context are allowed in javascript for historical reasons (old coders were sloppy) - note, `let` and `const` do not behave like `var` ... `function` are also hoisted, the difference with functions is that the definition is hoisted not just declaration

Comment: You need `var` initially, then never again. So you should do `var x = 10;` and `x = x + 1` inside. But that doesn't change that the condition evaluates to false and the code inside the if block doesn't run.

Comment: sorry, I was confused by the IF code line

Answer (score 0):

> Description
>
> var declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code
> is executed. This is called hoisting and is discussed further below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description

This means it does not matter where is your "var x", when this script is processed, the declaration will be the first.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand how [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) actually work.

```js
// You define 'x' variable [1] in global scope 
x = 10;


if (x > 1) {
  // You define another one 'x' variable inside of 'if' scope
  // So here (inside of 'if') you will interact with this variable,
  // not with first one ([1])
  var x = x + 1;
}

// You code run out of 'if' so you're working with 
// global scope again, and your 'x' is first one [1]
console.log(x); // x = 10 still 
var x;
```